# how can I calculate exponential fraction

Tags: c++, exponential

If I want to calculate 5.24^3.2478. The base and exponential is fractional. 
Is there some function to realize it?

the base of frexp is 2.

Comment: pow? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/

Comment: Have you tried the [pow](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) function?

Comment: search engine 'calculate exponential fraction c++' - this works for many subjects

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you mentioned **C++** in the tag, try one of this method:

```
double pow (double base     , double exponent);
float pow (float base      , float exponent);
long double pow (long double base, long double exponent);
double pow (Type1 base      , Type2 exponent); // additional overloads
```

Returns `base` raised to the power `exponent`.

See [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) here.